# Is GLMM appropriate with repeated measures and pseudo-replication?

Tags: r, mixed-model, generalized-linear-model, repeated-measures

My dataset is looking at the change in a person's blood pressure every day as a response to their exercise performed.

I have 20 subjects and I measure the blood pressure 5 times a day.

I do this for two months, and some patients having up to 50 entries in the dataset.

I also have a categorical variable of the exercise performed that day (1=none, 2=light, 3=mod, 4=heavy).

If the blood pressure is not normally distributed, is it best to use a GLMM, with exercise as a fixed effect and patient as a random effect?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: "If the blood pressure is not normally distributed" The distribution of the dependent variable is mostly irrelevant for regression. We only care about the distribution of model residuals. However, blood pressure is strictly positive. That and other properties of the dependent should be taken into consideration. Depending on your assumptions regarding model errors (and linearity, ...), a GLMM could be appropriate.